# Angular remove base url from post requests

Tags: angular

I have the below service in Angular 4 and when i'm trying to post information to my server it apply "http://localhost:4200" to my requests and the result is "http://localhost:4200/localhost:5000/login". How i can resolve this ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public authFunc(payload) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(this.http.post);

    return this.http.post("http:/localhost:5000/login", payload, {headers: headers});
  }
}
```

Comment: You’ve missed a `/` - it should be `http://`.

Comment: It was the mistake. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

`return this.http.post("/login", payload, {headers: headers});`

Edit: Do you have a web server running on port 5000 ?